# Simulating pressing the mute/volume up/volume down keys in Linux

Tags: linux, x11, keypress, mute

I've read up on the internet about how to simulate keypresses on the keyboard in the X window system.  So far, I've got a program, written in C, that works at sending key events from the traditional keys on the keyboard.  However, I can't figure out a way to simulate someone pressing the keyboard's mute/volume up/volume down keys.

This may not even be possible to do with the XKeyEvent structure I used for the previous key presses, since I didn't find anything remotely close in the keysymdef.h file, and I think that those events are delivered to the host OS rather than each individual window.

I've also fired up xev and it didn't give me very much helpful output (or at least any that I could decipher).

Does anyone have any tips on where I should look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with keycode 123 keysym 269025043 for volume up (xF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume)
and Keycode 122 keysym 269025041 (xF86XK_AudioLowerVolume), hope that helps